# What kind of permission does firebase auth need regarding twitter? (read, read and write, ...)

Tags: firebase, twitter, firebase-authentication, twitter-oauth

What kind of permission does firebase auth need regarding twitter? (read, read and write, ...)

I am not sure which option to choose. (I think read-only is enough)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just go with `Read-only` for authenticating. `Write` is for writing tweets or updating the bio, etc.